# How to have Installshield 2012 iscmdbld.exe command-line tool modify multiple properties

Tags: installshield, installshield-2011

I am trying to do an automated build and have my build server pass some command-line options to iscmdbld.exe in order to modify windows installer properties in the resulting msi file. I was able to get it working with one property change, but now I want change two and the second one doesn't seem to work.

Currently I am using the following options to build the app:

```
    -y "2.50.0100" -z "APP_VERSION=2.5.0.0.1" -z "APP_COMMENTS= Customer ID Version 2.5.0.0.1"
```

The part that doesn't seem to work is the second -z command-line option for the second property. Any thoughts?

PS. I used the installshield-2011 tag since I couldn't create one for 2012 and this should be basically the same in 2011 and 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a new Basic MSI project, added a dummy feature and component and built it with the multiple -z arguments as you typed them and it worked for me without any problems.  I looked at the output MSI's Property table and the values were there as expected.

Do you get any errors in your logfile?

BYW, IsCmdBld is fine and all,  but when you get into more complicated build scenarios you might appreciate the use of InstallShield's MSBuild support and COM Automation Interface to run your builds.

For example, I find it far easier to do this bit of XML then know to pass -z arguments to some EXE.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <InstallShieldProductVersion>$(MSIProductVersion)</InstallShieldProductVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <InstallShieldPropertyOverrides Include="$(CustomLongProductVersion)">
    <Property>APP_VERSION</Property>
  </InstallShieldPropertyOverrides>
  <InstallShieldPropertyOverrides Include=" Customer ID Version $(CustomLongProductVersion)">
    <Property>APP_COMMENTS</Property>
  </InstallShieldPropertyOverrides>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: At the moment, I can't integrate it with MSBuild (business reasons), but it's something I'll definitely keep in mind for the future. As far as the log file, I only get two warnings that are about including .NET Framework and MSXML.

Comment: I went ahead re-created my build configuration and ran it again and worked. Not sure what the issue was really, but this is the proper method through the command line.